A confusing sign in Maxwell's equations with differential forms
I'm running into a basic issue with Maxwell's equations in terms of differential forms. Let's work in Minkowski space with mostly negative signature, and define the Hodge star in the usual way,
$$\star (dx^{\mu_1} \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^{\mu_p}) = \frac{1}{(d-p)!} \, \epsilon_{\nu_1 \cdots \nu_d} \eta^{\mu_1 \nu_1} \cdots \eta^{\mu_p \nu_p} \, dx^{\nu_{p+1}} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{\nu_d} \tag{1}
$$
where $\epsilon_{0123} = 1$. In this signature, the Lagrangian is
$$\mathcal{L} = - \frac14 F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} - A^\mu j_\mu. \tag{2}$$
Translating this to differential forms, by defining the 3-form $J = \star j$, gives
$$\mathcal{L} = - \frac12 F \wedge \star F - A \wedge J. \tag{3}$$
To find the equation of motion, let's use the fact that
$$d(A \wedge \star F) = dA \wedge \star F - A \wedge (d \star F) \tag{4}$$
where the minus sign comes from passing $d$ through the one-form $A$. Discarding a boundary term,
$$\mathcal{L} = - \frac12 A \wedge (d \star F) - A \wedge J \tag{5}$$
from which we read off the equation of motion
$$d \star F = -J. \tag{6}$$
Now, every textbook resource I've found says the opposite, $d \star F = J$. But that makes sense, because all of them worked in mostly positive signature. In that case, I believe the manipulations above go through unchanged, except that the Lagrangian has to contain $+A^\mu j_\mu$, giving an overall sign flip.
However, I've only been able to find one good source that works in mostly negative signature, which is these polished lecture notes. They have the exact same definitions (1) through (3), but then immediately conclude (skipping equations (4) and (5)) that $d \star F = J$, which is the opposite of what I have. Am I missing something very basic here? What's the sign supposed to be in mostly negative signature?
